# Ubuntu shellscript

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am completely noob with Ubuntu, so sorry if what i am gonna ask is stupid or impossible.

I am running some tests on android phones, and after I finish it, I need to replace some data at xmlResults and run the tests again. I am trying to create a script to do it.
But I don't know how to run a command inside my program.

This is my script (as I said, completely noob):

```
sed -i 's/\"fail\"/\"notExecuted\"/g' testResult.xml 
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
cd tools
./cts-tradefed
run cts --continue-session 0
```

But the last line, run cts --continue-session 0, needs to be executed inside CTS program. I don't how to put this right, but after executing this ./cts-tradefed, I need to insert the next line inside CTS program.

Does it make sense? =p

I tried and it didn't work...

Comment: You mean the last line is supposed to be a parameter to the `cts-tradefed` executable?

Comment: Can please paraphrase your question.... I read it 5 times and no clue what you are trying to say

Comment: yes and no... It cannot be executed as a parameter... after I execute cts-tradefed, the "shell" changes and become cts-tf >   . I usually type the next command after it... i don't know if I can use it as argument

Comment: Sorry @NullSoulException, I don´t speak english natively and don´t know anything about Ubuntu... so I get lost with terms =p

Comment: Try: `./cts-tradefed run cts --continue-session 0`

Comment: @glennjackman was right. It is just as simple as you said. I had never tried to run this command as parameter...

Comment: I'd never heard of it until now, but a google search revealed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
sed -i 's/\"fail\"/\"notExecuted\"/g' testResult.xml 
../../../tools/cts-tradefed <<< "run cts --continue-session 0"
```

Although it's unclear if your `cts-tradefed` program needs to accept further input after the `run ...` line, or is in any other way interactive, which would complicate things. Also, if `cts-tradefed` is finicky about the directory it's run from, which *might* be the reason you have all those `cd` commands, you should at least condense them down to a single `cd` command, and then run the tool:

```
cd ../../../tools
./cts-tradefed .....
```